# How can I set a custom value for the @JsonProperty annotation, when generating a client using the kotlin-spring OpenApi generator?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm generating an API client from Open API specs (3.0.0), using openapi-generator:5.4.0 and kotlin-spring generator.

The generated data classes for the models have the @JsonProperty annotation. The value of the annotation is the same as the name of the property. I want to have different values for the annotation and the property name.

This is because the specs represent a 3rd party API which does not use meaningful names for its properties. I want to set descriptive names for the properties, and use the 3rd party's names in the @JsonProperty annotation. This way, Json parsing will not fail when I use those models for API calls.

Is there some way to achieve this?

For reference, here's a

sample spec: [link to full spec](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin/samples/local-spec/petstore-v3.0.yaml)

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
```

generated data class:

```kotlin
data class Pet(

    @field:JsonProperty("id", required = true) val id: kotlin.Long,

    @field:JsonProperty("name", required = true) val name: kotlin.String,

    @field:JsonProperty("tag") val tag: kotlin.String? = null
) {

}
```

and build.gradle.kts file:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "5.3.0"
    application
}

group = "io.codextor"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.openapitools:openapi-generator:5.4.0")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}

tasks.withType<GenerateTask> {
    generatorName.set("kotlin-spring")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/specs/petstore-v3.0.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")
    apiPackage.set("org.openapi.example.api")
    invokerPackage.set("org.openapi.example.invoker")
    modelPackage.set("org.openapi.example.model")
    configOptions.set(
        mapOf(
            "dateLibrary" to "java8"
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but it may be possible using custom mustache templates.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the annotation

```
@field:JsonProperty
```

to be generated, you need to modify your configOptions in the build.gradle.kts to

```
mapOf(
    "dateLibrary" to "java8",
    "serializationLibrary" to "jackson" 
)
```

More such config values can be found on https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md